# How to provide single bean definition for all child class in spring configuration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I am new to spring and exploring it, I want to my spring container to create all objects from a specific package.

Circle Class:

```
@Component
public class Circle extends AbstractShape  {

@Override
public void draw() {

}

@Override
public int calculateArea(int x, int y) {
    return (int) (3.14 * x * y);
}
```

}

Square Class:

```
@Component
public class Square extends AbstractShape {
    @Override
    public void draw() {

    }

    @Override
    public int calculateArea(int x, int y) {
        return x * y;
    }
}
```

My spring config class which basically create bean defination for me:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class ShapeConfig {

    @Bean
    public Circle getCircle() {
        return new Circle();
    }

    @Bean
    public Square getSquare() {
        return new Square();
    }
}
```

I want my bean definition to be created which extends class "AbstractShape", and want to avoid providing one by one bean definition in my config class. Please suggest possible ways to do so.

Thanks in Advance,

Priyank

Comment: I am not sure if I get you right - but why can't you annotate Circle and Square as @Component?

Comment: Sorry I missed that part. I already annotated as @Component.

Answer (score 2):

Annotating the class `Circle` and `Square` itself with `@Component` is much easier for a task like this.

This method is identical to declaring a method in a `@Configuration` class, the way you are doing now.

You can try annotating the `AbstractShape` class, I don't know from the top of my head if it works

Comment: I already tagged "Circle" and "Square" as @Component. and annotating Abstract class is not a good idea. because you can not instantiate an abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

It got resolved by adding @ComponenetScan at configuration.

Thanks for your answers.